# Can't construct a query for the property

Tags: angular, jestjs, karma-jasmine

```
   Can't construct a query for the property "someproperty" of "someComponent" since the query selector wasn't defined.

  

32 |
      33 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 34 |     await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         |                   ^
      35 |       declarations: [declareComponent],
      36 |       schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      37 |       imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
```

When unit testing above component, getting above error.